# piping Linux cat command to web in openWRT

Tags: shell, curl, serial-port, arduino, openwrt

I want to run a shell script from openWRT. Basically its need to constantly read arduino serial port and when its reads something its need to be sent to a web based service.

Currently this is my script which only save to text file:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0  >> /www/home/log.txt &
```

I want to avoid saving to file and send the output string right to a web based service that store the readings in mySQL DB.

All the data saving web service is all set and working something like this:

http://my-service.com/?data=what-ever-the-arduino-spits

Is there a way to do it with wget?

maybe something like this:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 | xargs -n % wget http://ivardi.info?todb=%
```

keep in mind that the openWRT is on a 32 RAM and 4MB flash storage so this is only possible with shell script and not Phyton/PHP.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it could be dangerous in some cases to directly read the serial (`/dev/ttyACM0`) device and pass it direct to `wget` in case the read blocked for some reason (what happens if the serial port is disconnected and reconnected?)

It could be safer to route the output to a file; then in a loop read the most recent data and 'pushing' that using `wget`. Perhaps something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    tail -1 /www/home/log/txt | wget <...options...>
    sleep 60
done
```

In reality you would probably need to do something a little more advanced so that you don't keep sending duplicate data.

Of course, in your own situation what you proposed may be sufficient...